# How to set the value of the y-axis' labels in a bar plot to only show the numbers -1, 0 and 1 (without decimals of values in between)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot made with ggplot2::

[image]

How can I hide some of the labels on the y-axis? I only want to show the labels -1, 0, and 1 (without decimal points).

I am plotting 4 subplots (2x2) in a figure, using `ggplot2` and `patchwork` (to add tags). I am using `coord_flip()` to show the y-values on the bottom. However, when I export the final figure, the max width I can have for my figure (180mm) makes the y-labels overlap. So I wanted to:

1. only show the values -1, 0 and 1 in all the subplots y-axis
2. Remove decimals (like, it is showing -1.0, and I wanted to show only -1).

Here is the script I'm using:

```
Nmx_c1_plot <- ggplot(dataNmxc1,aes(x=Parameter,y=Val, fill = Pathway)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_dodge()) +
    coord_flip()+
    scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE), breaks = pretty_breaks())
  

Hpx_c1_plot <- ggplot(dataHpxc1,aes(x=Parameter,y=Val, fill = Pathway)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_dodge()) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE), breaks = pretty_breaks())

Nmx_c2_plot <- ggplot(dataNmxc2,aes(x=Parameter,y=Val, fill = Pathway)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_dodge()) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE), breaks = pretty_breaks())

Hpx_c2_plot <- ggplot(dataHpxc2,aes(x=Parameter,y=Val, fill = Pathway)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_dodge())+ 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE), breaks = pretty_breaks())

patchwork <- Nmx_c1_plot +Nmx_c2_plot +Hpx_c1_plot+ Hpx_c2_plot 
SensFig <- patchwork + plot_annotation(tag_levels = list(c("(A)","(B)","(C)","(D)")))
```

I tried adding the line: `scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE), breaks = pretty_breaks())`

Which led to the current image I have, but still I couldn't make all plots show the -1,0,1. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way using breaks and labels:

```
scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE), breaks = c(-1,0,1),labels = c('-1','0','1'),limits = c(-1,1))
```